# using blender, what are the coding steps required to design a walking person animation and export as JSON

Tags: json, animation, 3d, three.js, blender-2.76

My requirement is "i need to display walking person animation on web based on the character model(JSON) designed from Blender"

Pls let me know in detail the steps it has to be followed.

Thanks

ASH

Comment: Initially, i think we need to add three.js plugin to blender(vers 2.77) to export as json. Based on the link (http://pixelchinchilla.com/2014/05/cmc-6-how-to-use-three-js-export-plugin-in-blender/) i copied the scripts folder to  Blender directory (C:\Users\<your_username>\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<blender_version>\)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Add Three.js plugin to Blender(vers 2.7)

Step 2) Using Blender, as per the link(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krEoAjK-vo0) import the image and change the relavant paramters as the steps shown in the link.

Step 3) Once the image is converted into 3d model, export the file as JSON. Ensure it has the following parameters **metadata, scale, materials, vertices, morphTargets(face,height,hands etc),normals and faces** are available in the JSON

step 4) To display on the web, import the json into html file(three.js) using THREE.XHRLoader() and run the same. It should display the 3d model image.

Thanks
ASH